# Android Studio : I encounter UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android

I think this is because the third jars clash.

> 06-30 15:13:06.347 24088-24088/com.tryking.timer E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.tryking.timer, PID: 24088
>                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex
>   file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-weiboSDKCore_3.1.4_c86c77fdba6782f5d16e0f2354aecb1f74a84895-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-umeng_social_sdk_89b67e62778b9e27c98c04e0c97acdc4c57343a6-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_abd0890c72058e463bf8e33224e89840708f8b48-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-ormlite-core-4.48_0c1f5132b5b67b94438fe9ad50aa92bd0ecc9641-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-ormlite-android-4.48_f36ef3b839478551d009ded9878c754102a43305-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-open_sdk_r5509_fedb21b7748c46435febcc465978e4cfe67f43e6-classes.dex", dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mta-sdk-1.6.2_0569a9a50fea12aae476d6171e5ea92e41c742e0-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-library-2.4.0_dd460f45d27a359687729c3c169358b1eda3100b-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-library-1.0.19_78f0bb23743784ba5177d1b9659f6fa6d6a7bd06-classes.dex", dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_55c6a5800bee523ae97132191c756e4456f8dcb2-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-intermediates-exploded-aar-SMSSDKGUI-2.1.0_efd037d30b0ee879af4bd34b0404099fec2caf25-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-intermediates-exploded-aar-SMSSDK-2.1.0_910c09d6d432b52ee0ef0b00eea687173c9f347e-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.prolificinteractive-material-calendarview-1.4.0_ede51e1e2af95aec8fc5e70517a12db85bdd9f56-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.orhanobut-logger-1.11_7fcf574bfc8e924c0418411267832c0c503b2618-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.fresco-imagepipeline-base-0.11.0_2c860a106ca050bd7c4cfc1fbf75e5a3a3674e9c-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.fresco-imagepipeline-0.11.0_2c07b6c96ee32176eeaabe745fe5340a061f2aef-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.fresco-fresco-0.11.0_77539e73436ac9149743a4162fc7257bd77a1047-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.fresco-fbcore-0.11.0_62a35c3d682bf39d05df4ac3ce4886e4b4c8c79c-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.fresco-drawee-0.11.0_1edcfadae7eac0ca063ecddf005f07faf2b48a29-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.tryking.timer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.3.0_fe2c83ec628faa45871ae842

Comment: please reformat your code and ask properly whats a problem update build gradle also

Comment: try to disable Instant Run feature in Android Studio first. Then run again.

Comment: I try.But I encounter a new problem.

Comment: **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.tryking.timer, PID: 27904
                                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tryking.timer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tryking.timer-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsmssdk.so"**